# FlinkKafkaConsumer / KafkaSource with AWS Glue Schema Registry or Confluent Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, aws-glue, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I'm trying to write an Flink streaming application that has a KafkaSource to read from a topic which has an AVRO schema defined for its data.

I would like to know how the automatic caching of schemas locally works in this case similar to Confluent's documentation [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html#schemas-subjects-and-topics).

Basically, the use-case is that a consumer should not know the schema beforehand. Once the consumer is instantiated, the schema registry URL should be taken as a parameter and the consumer should read the schema for that particular topic.

Is this possible? Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: The glue deserializers are open source... They work very similarly to the Confluent ones with regards to this. What specific issues are you having?

Comment: Yes, Glue schema registry is basically a copy of the confluent one. The `FlinkKafkaConsumer` requires consumers to know the schema beforehand. I was wondering if this can be avoided by making the schema for consumer be read from schema registry directly and cached locally - how they've described here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html#schemas-subjects-and-topics. My issue is that our consumers will not know the schema beforehand and they should be able to create a `FlinkKafkaConsumer` client using the Glue or Confluent schema registry URL.

Comment: No, it cannot be avoided because Avro requires **two schemas**. The data consumed in the topic is the "writer schema". If you have the registry endpoint, you can simply use HTTP client to fetch a "reader schema". Problem is not unique to Flink; you will see any other Avro Kafka consumer pre-compile/download a separate Avro "reader schema" locally to deserialize the records. This is what is referred to by "schema evolution" - you provide one schema locally to map previously written data into.

Comment: So, after the initial schema load, any updates to schema that gets updated on schema registry (Glue or otherwise) will work with auto schema update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS SerDe libraries for Glue use a wire format that containes the uuid of the schema (version) the message is serialized with.
The consuming application reads the schema id from the message, and loads it from the Glue schema registry, if it's not in the local cache already.
You can find a description of the wire format at the bottom of the readme for this javascript serde library:
https://github.com/meinestadt/glue-schema-registry .

Comment: Thanks Felix, this is what I was able to achieve with Confluent. But for the Glue, I don’t see a CachedSchenaRegistryClient to cache the schema fetched. My application is using Java client. Let me check again.

Comment: I tried to follow the byte array format, but getting an exception. Looks like byte 2 through 18 is not having the schema ID. I'm doing the following: `ByteBuffer schemaIdBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(value, 2, 16);` Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Why can’t you use the official Glue SerDe libraries for Java from AWS? 
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry ?

Comment: Or can you share one example binary message you are trying to decode? Then I can have a look at the format. You can share it as hex string, for example.

Comment: I used the official SerDe from aws and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

> Once the consumer is instantiated, the schema registry URL should be taken as a parameter and the consumer should read the schema for that particular topic.

It will, and that will be cached. This is known as the "writer schema".

> consumer should not know the schema beforehand

It needs to since Avro requires a "reader schema" to deserialize data defined by the "writer schema".

Without a reader schema, you are left with handling Avro `GenericRecord` types

Comment: I was doing some reading and found this resource where Python Kafka Consumer code snippet (in the description of the video) does not take the schema as input. Not sure if I'm missing anything here.
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7XFcfE_TJ0

Comment: Not sure what you mean. They are using `schema_file.read()`

Comment: Also, Python in particular is untyped, so that falls in the case of the `GenericRecord` JVM type, where you dont need a local schema file

Comment: They're doing that on the producer side I guess.

Comment: Oh, if we are ok with having `GenericRecord`, is it possible with Flink consumer + glue  as well?

Comment: Should be. It's just Avro API at that point. Any SpecificRecord can be downcast to a generic one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251084/discussion-between-guru-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: I've really only used Beam. I don't have example Flink code available

Comment: I tried to run the application using Confluent schema registry as well. I see unexpected results that don't make complete sense to me. I have 2 records in a source topic. r1 is with schema v1, and r2 is with schema v2. I provided s1 as part of the `forGeneric` method and provided the schema registry URL as well. Looks like the schema registry is not even read by the consumer client. Why is that?

Comment: I don't see how auto schema fetch / cached schema works with Flink or schema registry in general. If it always uses reader schema even though writer schema is a newer version and is compatible, what is the point of having a schema registry for clients to use? Could you please help me understand what I'm missing here?

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't use Flink, and that isn't even the issue here. Flink delegates to non-Flink Kafka-native Avro deserializer classes... You only get the cached schema if you use `GenericRecord`, as mentioned. Otherwise, you have a compiled Avro schema as a `SpecificRecord`, so the "writer schema" (one sent by the Producer, which sets the ID in the bytes), is converted into that via Avro evolution policies. There is an [example in the docs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/tree/master/avro-flink-serde) using GenericRecord

Comment: thanks for all your help - appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

This should be possible.

You can test with a Kafka CLI tool like `kcat` like this:

`kcat -b mybroker -t ledger -s avro -r http://schema-registry-url:8080`

If you are using `kafka-avro-console-consumer`:

`kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic topicX --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 \  --property schema.registry.url="http://schema-registry:8081"`

Comment: What does this have to do with Flink or AWS Glue?

Comment: It is possible via regular kafka avro consumer, I know this. I want to be able to do the same thing with `FlinkKafkaConsumer` - providing just the Glue schema registry URL or Confluent Schema Registry URL.